# Get iOS screen resolution without UI in MonoTouch

Tags: c#, ios, user-interface, xamarin.ios, uikit

The question is: how can I get screen resolution in iOS MonoTouch (like `UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds`) without a UI thread? 
The property `.MainScreen` throws an exception

```
UIKit Consistency error: you are calling a UIKit method that can only be invoked from the UI thread.
```

Thus I need a UI thread. But since the resolution is needed before the application is loaded, before `UIApplication.Main()` gets called, `UIApplication.mainThread` (a private member, shown by the debugger) is `null`. I assume there is no UI thread at all since there is no UI. So I technically can not call `InvokeOnMainThread` on any object.

Is there any other way to obtain screen resolution without `UIScreen.MainScreen`? If not, I will have to move initialization to some code invoked from UI. Then there's another question: how do I get any UI object (to call `InvokeOnMainThread`) from arbitrary thread? I do not have control over the UI code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UI thread checks are [optional](http://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2012/Sep-10.html) and can be disabled, either globally or locally. The later (locally) option seems to fit what you need.

The following code will turn off the check, get the bounds and re-enable the check (if it was previously enabled).

```
bool check_ui = UIApplication.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls;
UIApplication.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCall = false;
var screen_bounds = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
UIApplication.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = check_ui;
```

Comment: It worked! Is it thread-safe if I do nothing with MainScreen but read `Bounds`?

Comment: It's **not** thread-safe but if you're doing this before `UIApplication.Main()` is called then you are *likely* (if you did not create some threads) on the **main** thread - which will be the UI thread (but our check is not yet initialized).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I am indeed on the main thread. But I wonder why reading a (not changing) value is not threads-safe? I understand why (possibly) `.MainWindow` `get` is not thread safe: I can do all sort of things with it. Maybe the `get` of `MainScreen` does something non-thread-safe?

Comment: The general rule is that **UIKit is not thread safe**. You cannot know how the value is initialized/computed - so having more than one thread requesting `Bounds` can break (if not protected). When Apple documents methods as thread-safe then we mark them as such (and no exception is thrown).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the first question, but for the second question "how do I get any UI object (to call InvokeOnMainThread) from arbitrary thread?", how about this?

```cs
new NSObject().InvokeOnMainThread(() => {   
    //call UI specific stuff
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know NSObject is that clever it knows about UI thread regardless of creation method.